# Gross percentage of files that are identical between two projects

Tags: diff

I'm examining two different projects, using the command:

```
diff --brief -r project1/ project2/
```

I was able to see the files between them that are not the same.

Ultimately what I'd like to do is to show the overall percentage of files that are changed between them, the formula would probably be something like:

`all files in project 1` **+** `all files in project 2` **-** `files they have in common`...

but of course that isn't right. What should the formula look like?

What is a command I can use that is the opposite of diff, to show all the files that are identical between the two folders?

Answer (score 1):

Use the --report-identical-files flag (alias: -s)

```
diff --report-identical-files --brief -r project1/ project2/
```

EDIT:

As to the formula, it should look like ( #same / #files ) * 100%